# UDP source port changed - not using binded port

Tags: java, linux, sockets, udp, netty

My Java/Netty application is binded to port 20500:

```
java     5847 ----   92u  IPv6  93413      0t0  UDP *:20500
```

Application send UDP message:

```
DatagramPacket(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:20500 => /200.72.211.71:16207, UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 19, cap: 256))
```

Wireshark captured message:

```
72835   4550.811346000  192.168.1.11    200.72.211.71   UDP 61  Source port: 1024  Destination port: 16207
```

Notice that source port of the actual message in Wireshark is *1024*, Java application is binded to port *20500*, and the Datagram port is *20500*.

Why UDP source port is being changed by linux (or Netty)?

Comment: How do you know that the wireshark message that was captured is the same one sent by your application?

Comment: @BrianCain Because I'm washing my app log and wireshark at the same time. Whenever the app log, the message appears...

Comment: Are you sure you don't have independent listening socket and unbound socket for transmitting that is using an ephemeral port?

Comment: @BrianCain I'm sure that at the moment of flushing the message this is my local address: 192.168.1.11:20500. therefore ports don't match...